# Why pass a string argument to raise Exception()

Tags: python

I'm working through a chapter on exceptions in Python and the author gives the following example, some different exceptions are stored in a list, one or none is chosen randomly and handled:

```
import random
some_exceptions = [ValueError, TypeError, IndexError, None]

try:
    choice = random.choice(some_exceptions)
    print(f'raising {choice}')
    if choice:
        raise choice('An Error') # Don't understand the need for the 'An Error' argument
except ValueError:
    print('Caught a ValueError')
except TypeError:
    print('Caught a TypeError')
except Exception as e:
    print(f'Caught some other error: {e.__class__.__name__}')
else:
    print('This code is called if there is no exception')
finally:
    print('This code is always called')
```

I don't understand the line `raise choice('An Error')`, the words 'An Error' are never output to the console and the example appears to work just as well with that line changed to `raise choice()`, is there any specific reason the author did this?

Comment: It's not printing simply because the author is not printing it. To see it you should write: `except SomeException as e: print('Exception', e)`

Comment: If you didn't catch the error with `except`, the message would be printed by the default exception handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exceptions are classes too. the string are parameter passed to the class.

```
In [10]: help(ValueError)

In [11]: v = ValueError("value is not accepted.")

In [12]: v
Out[12]: ValueError('value is not accepted.')

In [13]: v.args
Out[13]: ('value is not accepted.',)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use Try catch in python in this way:

```
choice = ValueError
try:
    raise choice('An Error')
except ValueError as e:
    print(e)
```

You will get "An Error" printed it is useful to customize output error so you can know where the error happened like so:

```
choice = ValueError
a = int(input("Enter a number a"))
b = int(input("Enter a number b"))
try:
    error = "No error"
    if a == 0:
        error = "a is Null"
    if b == 0:
        error = "b is Null"
    raise choise(error)
except ValueError as e:
    print(e)
```

In this code you can track From where the error comes from if you do for example a division by a or b and you get a Null division error

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions are classes. If you write your own (deriving e.g. from ValueError) the constructor of instance creation - this is what do by writing `ValueError()` - may store this string to be output by the `__str__` method of the exception. So if the exception type is insufficient for pinpointing the reason the string argument may prove useful.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused how the raise command works. It takes a class which already has some inbuilt some stuff like an Exception class. It cannot raise exception on any class. If you need to raise that message, go about like

```
import random
some_exceptions = [ValueError, TypeError, IndexError, None]

try:
    choice = random.choice(some_exceptions)
    print(f'raising {choice}')
    if choice:
        raise Exception('An Error') # Don't understand the need for the 'An Error' argument
except ValueError:
    print('Caught a ValueError')
except TypeError:
    print('Caught a TypeError')
except Exception as e:
    print(f'Caught some other error: {e.__class__.__name__}')
else:
    print('This code is called if there is no exception')
finally:
    print('This code is always called')
```

Answer (score 1):

It is just the common usage. Exceptions (derived from `BaseException`) have an `args` member which contains the parameters passed at creation time, so they can accept 0 to n parameters. Nevertheless the doc for `BaseException.args` says (emphasize mine):

> The tuple of arguments given to the exception constructor. Some built-in exceptions (like OSError) expect a certain number of arguments and assign a special meaning to the elements of this tuple, while **others are usually called only with a single string** giving an error message.

Answer (score 1):

These both are type errors (in native python), but see how the custom message is different

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> a['d']

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

>>> 1 in 'fs'

TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not int
```

And so, to generate a custom error message which is subset of an existing class you can do this:

```
>>> raise TypeError('meaningless type error')

TypeError: meaningless type error
```